# Can't add (int, double) pair to HashMap<Integer, Double>

Tags: java, types

I'm working on a Java project right now, and I have a class I've created called DistanceQueue. It's signature is given by

```
public class DistanceQueue<Integer> extends PriorityQueue<Integer>
```

In this class, there is a method

```
public boolean add(int v)
```

which adds the key-value pair (v, Double.MAX_VALUE) to a HashMap called distances that is in the class DistanceQueue. However, inside of add(int v), when I type

```
distances.put(v, Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

I get the following error:

```
DistanceQueue.java:98: error: no suitable method found for put(int,double)
            distances.put(v, Double.MAX_VALUE);
                     ^
    method HashMap.put(Integer,Double) is not applicable
      (actual argument int cannot be converted to Integer by method invocation conversion)
  where Integer is a type-variable:
    Integer extends Object declared in class ShortestPaths.DistanceQueue
1 error
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? I thought Java automatically converted between int and Integer for you. Is there an easy way that I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `distances`?

Comment: distances is a HashMap. It was created with

HashMap<Integer, Double> distances = new HashMap<Integer, Double>()

Comment: I've surely seen duplicates of this question before but they are really hard to search for since they tend to have random problem descriptions that don't hint to the actual problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're using `Integer` as the name of a type parameter, which *hides* the `java.lang.Integer`.

```
public class DistanceQueue<Integer> extends PriorityQueue<Integer>
                           ^^^^^^^
```

You should probably just drop the type parameter:

```
public class DistanceQueue extends PriorityQueue<Integer>
```

Comment: So how would I change my approach so that I can insert into the HashMap?

Comment: `public class DistanceQueue extends PriorityQueue<Integer>`